# How to add a Property Meta tag programmatically to head section

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, header, metadata

I would like to add the following meta tag below but do it dynamically when the page loads so that in case we do not need to add it we will not.

```
<meta property="example" content="example" />
```

This is in VB.Net with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
    Dim tempMeta As New HtmlMeta
    Dim tempHead As HtmlHead = Page.Header
    With tempMeta
        .Attributes.Add("property", "example")
        .Content = "example"
    End With
    tempHead.Controls.Add(tempMeta)
```

Edit:  Sorry, I had missed the "property" attribute in your question.